# Nuxt: Set layout in page.vue dynamically based on data

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Can I set the layout in my page based on a data variable?

I have the following folder structure:

```
layouts/
--default.vue
--custom.vue
pages/
--page.vue
```

I tried this in Page.vue:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return { value: '' }
  },
  layout () { this.value === 'a' ? 'custom' : 'default' }
  async asyncData ({...}) { //value is set here }
```

But it returns the error "cannot read property 'value' of undefined".
How can I access what's in data to dynamically decide which layout the page should use?

Answer (score 21):

The [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-layout) says that layout can also be a function (with access to the context).

```
export default {
  layout: 'blog',
  // OR
  layout (context) {
    return 'blog'
  }
}
```

I guess that in the [context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context) is everything you need.

Comment: How can I get to the page's data through the context?

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible, but perhaps you can make a workaround with the vuex store or with collecting the data outside your coponent and use it within the component but also within the layout method

Answer (score 3):

`layout ({$auth}) { return $auth.loggedIn ? 'layout1' : 'layout2' }`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -5):

You cannot change layout dynamically in page because layout is parent of this page and you cannot change it from it's child

So try it to fetch data in layout and change it in layout level !